# how to evaluate integral that contains HeunT in it?

Tags: maple

I am trying to plot solution obtained from ODE solution which has in it an integral from 0..x. The integral contains `HeunT` special function. Maple is very slow in producing the plot, and traced it down to it not being able or slow in evaluating this integral. It just says `evaluating` at the bottom of the window.

Here is the part of the solution which contains the integral, copied as is from notebook

```
r := Int(exp((2/3)*(-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/2)*_z1*
      (3*Pi^2+3*Pi*_z1+_z1^2))/HeunT(0, 0, 0, (1/3)*3^(2/3)*
       (-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/6)*2^(1/3)*(_z1+Pi))^2, _z1 = 0 .. x)
```

To plot the solution, this integral needs to be evaluated for different
`x` values. But Maple can't evaluate this integral for any `x` it seems. For example

```
evalf(subs(x=Pi,r));
```

Maple just keeps saying evaluating.... Is there a way to evaluate this integral, which is part of the the full ODE solution (given below if needed), so I can actually plot the solution of the ODE?

Here is the complete code below, starting from the ODE itself. I am basically just trying to plot the solution for a boundary value sturm-Liouville ODE

```
restart;
lam:=n->(9*n^2/(49*Pi^4)):
ode:=diff(y(x),x$2)+lam*(x+Pi)^4*y(x)=0:
sol:=dsolve({ode,y(0)=0},y(x)):
sol:=subs({lam=lam(1),_C2=sqrt(6/(7*Pi^3))},sol);
```

The solution is, which is what I am trying to plot for `x=0..Pi`

```
sol := y(x) = (1/7)*42^(1/2)*exp(-(1/3)*(-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/2)*x*
 (3*Pi^2+3*Pi*x+x^2))*HeunT(0, 0, 0, (1/3)*3^(2/3)*
 (-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/6)*2^(1/3)*(x+Pi))*(Int(exp((2/3)*
 (-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/2)*_z1*(3*Pi^2+3*Pi*_z1+_z1^2))/
 HeunT(0, 0, 0, (1/3)*3^(2/3)*(-(9/49)/Pi^4)^(1/6)*2^(1/3)*
 (_z1+Pi))^2, _z1 = 0 .. x))/Pi^(3/2)
```

And you can see the integral mentioned at the top, is inside the solution.

Maple 2016, windows 7

Comment: You can expand the expression inside the `Int` into series and then `Int` it. `Int(convert(simplify(series(r, _z1, 3), size),polynom),_z1=0..1)
`

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal Maple17 is not released as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(Re(convert(simplify(series(rhs(sol), x, 3), size),polynom)),x=0..Pi)
```

[image]